# Hacer que aparezcan campos de diferentes tablas en formularios y consultas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Lo que quisiera hacer para que entiendan mejor es lo siguiente:

Tengo una tabla cliente con los siguientes campos:

```
IdCliente int not null primary key auto_increment;
Nombre varcjar;
Apellido varchar;
Direccion varchar;
Telefono varchar;
```

Una tabla de factura:

```
IdFactura int not null primary key auto_increment;
Tipo char;
Fecha datetime;
```

Y una tabla cliente_factura:

```
IdCliente
IdFactura
```

Entonces lo que quisiera primero es que en el formulario aparezca idcliente, nombre y apellido que seria sacado de la tabla cliente y luego cantidad de facturas que lo sacaria de alguna forma de facturas. Y aparte de eso que se pueda insertar,actualizar y eliminar esos datos. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

si lo que quieres es mostrar la data en un formlario seria mas o menos así.

```
<?php
  //Supongo que ya tienes echa la conexion
  $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT idcliente, nombre , apellido FROM datos", 
  $conexion);
  //No hacemos un while, porque sunpongo que solo quieres mostra un 
  resultado.
  $registros = mysql_fetch_row($consulta)
  ?>
//Ahora en los text que tengas por ai repartidos en la pagina pones lo siguiente:
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $registros['idcliente']?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $registros['nombre']?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $registros['apellido']?>">
// Y así tendrías en unos input de texto los valores devueltos por tu consulta,
```

pero ! Ojo¡ Sólo el primer registro devuelto por la consulta.

lo mismo para traer las facturas solo que en este caso usarias el while.

Comment: ¿Y con todo ese pedazo de codigo repetido solo para cantidad de facturas seria suficiente?Pensaba que había una forma de llamar campos de diferentes tablas en un mismo codigo o que talvez la solucion este en esa tabla en la que se relacionan.Lo que sea, si es la única forma la usaré entonces.

Comment: Suponiendo que tenemos el id de cliente, seria de esta manera, SELECT idcliente, nombre , apellido FROM Cliente  c inner join factura f on c.idcliente = f.idcliente where c.idcliente = $idcliente.


Te recomiendo crear las tablas de la siguiente manera, 

IdCliente int not null primary key auto_increment;
Nombre varcjar;
Apellido varchar;
Direccion varchar;
Telefono varchar;


Factura
IdFactura int not null primary key auto_increment;
Tipo char;
Fecha datetime;
IdCliente



DetalleFactura
idfactura
coditem
precioItem.

Comment: En realidad lo que necesitas es saber que es CRUD, te sugiero accedas a este link, hay un ejemplo básico de todo lo que quiere hacer.

http://www.codingcage.com/2014/12/simple-php-crud-operations-with-mysql.html

Comment: Si gracias se lo que es crud ya lo pude estudiar, solo que no se como relacionar campos de tablas diferentes para una consulta o formulario en si.

Comment: ahi me gustaria mas, quisiera saber mas en prpfundidad el codigo , creo que las tablas y campos estan creadas de la misma manera que vos lo expusiste